# Proxmox resize failed: exit code 1

Tags: virtual-machines, proxmox

How can I resize the hard disk in proxmox? When I have tried, I get the following error.

> "command '/usr/bin/qemu-img resize /var/lib/vz/pools/development/images/105/vm-105-disk-1.qcow235433480192' failed: exit code 1 (500)

[image: Resize error]

I am able to resize other virtual machine's hard disks.

What additional steps should I take to troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is caused because you have snapshots for that VM.

If you don't need them, you must first remove them and then you will be able to grow your disk.

If you need the snapshots, you will need to modify manually the config file for that VM. SSH to the node and modify the file `/etc/pve/qemu-server/VMID.conf` where VMID is the number ID of the VM.

Modify the size in the settings, both in the VM and all their snapshots.

Then boot the VM and follow these steps to let the guest OS know it has more available disk.

http://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Resizing_disks

We should open a bug report on proxmox.

Comment: Thank you for creating the bug report. For anyone interested it can be found [here](https://bugzilla.proxmox.com/show_bug.cgi?id=517).